# What kind of operation is available here?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tensor-products, tensors

What kind of operation $\clubsuit$ is available here?
$$
\underbrace{\left(v^{\mathrm T}A_{n\times n\times n}\right)}_{\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}}\underbrace{\left(v^{\mathrm T}B_{n\times n\times n}v\right)}_{\in\mathbb R^n}=v^{\mathrm T}\left(A_{n\times n\times n}\clubsuit B_{n\times n\times n}\right)vv
$$
where $A_{n\times n\times n}$ and $B_{n\times n\times n}$ are ${n\times n\times n}$-dimensional arrays, and $v\in\mathbb R^n$. (In order to let the above expression hold, $A$ and $B$ can be symmetric and so on)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In index notation the equation can be written $$\eqalign{(v_i A_{ijk}) \,\, (v_p B_{pkr} v_r) &= v_i \, (A_{ijk} B_{pkr}) \, v_pv_r}$$ so the product in question is a contraction between the rightmost index of $A$ and the middle index of $B$.

Comment: @lynn Thanks very much. Further for your equality, is there any rules?